# Query to update the JSON value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to query to update a table that has JSON data. The data of the column **detail** in the table **details** are as follows.

```
id     | 1

detail | {
   myCompany: [{ email: 'company@company.com', inProfit: true }],
   myData: [
      { email: 'example@example.com'},
      { email: 'test@test.com'},
      { email: 'test@example.com' },
   ],
};
```

The **JSON** value of the column **detail** is as follows

```
{
   "myCompany":[
      {
         "email":"company@company.com",
         "inProfit":true
      }
   ],
   "myData":[
      {
         "email":"example@example.com"
      },
      {
         "email":"test@test.com"
      },
      {
         "email":"test@example.com",
      }
   ]
}
```

I want a query that updates the `myData`. Add a new field `personalUse:true` for all fields of `myData` after `email`. For example, after running the update query the `myData` field should look like as follows,

```
"myData":[
      {
         "email":"example@example.com",
         "personalUse":true
      },
      {
         "email":"test@test.com",
         "personalUse":true
      },
      {
         "email":"test@example.com",
         "personalUse":true
      }
   ]
```

You can use the below queries to try it locally.

```
CREATE TABLE details (id bigserial primary key, detail json not null);

INSERT INTO details (detail) 
VALUES 
  ('{"myCompany":[{"email":"company@company.com", "inProfit":true } ],  
     "myData":[{"email":"example@example.com" }, 
               {"email":"test@test.com"},
               {"email":"test@example.com"} ] }');
```

Please, someone, help me out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several functions that may be helpful:

- `->` operator: gets JSON object field by key.
- `jsonb_agg`: aggregates values as a JSON array.
- `json_array_elements`: expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values.
- `jsonb_set`: replaces part of JSON designated by path with a value (or inserts it if the part is missing).

You can read more here:

- [Aggregate Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html)
- [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

### Query

```
update details
  set detail = jsonb_set(detail::jsonb, '{myData}', myData)
  from (
    select id, jsonb_agg(myData) as myData
      from (
        select
          id,
          jsonb_set(
            json_array_elements(detail->'myData')::jsonb,
            '{personalUse}',
            'true') as myData
          from details
      ) x
      group by id
  ) z
  where details.id = z.id;
```

### How it works

Expand `myData` arrays along with `id` into table.

```
user=# select id, json_array_elements(detail->'myData') as myData from details;
 id |                        mydata                         
----+-------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"email": "example@example.com"}
  1 | {"email": "test@test.com"}
  1 | {"email": "test@example.com"}
  2 | {"email": "tt@test.com"}
  2 | {"email": "tt@example.com"}
```

Use `jsonb_set` to update each object.

```
user=# select
user-#   id,
user-#   jsonb_set(
user(#     json_array_elements(detail->'myData')::jsonb,
user(#     '{personalUse}',
user(#     'true'
user(#   ) as myData
user-# from details;
 id |                        mydata                         
----+-------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"email": "example@example.com", "personalUse": true}
  1 | {"email": "test@test.com", "personalUse": true}
  1 | {"email": "test@example.com", "personalUse": true}
  2 | {"email": "tt@test.com", "personalUse": true}
  2 | {"email": "tt@example.com", "personalUse": true}
```

Use `jsonb_agg` to collect emails back into JSON array.

```
user=# select id, jsonb_agg(myData) as myData from (
user(#   select
user(#     id,
user(#     jsonb_set(
user(#       json_array_elements(detail->'myData')::jsonb,
user(#       '{personalUse}',
user(#       'true'
user(#     ) as myData
user(#   from details
user(# ) x group by id;
 id |
----+-------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | [{"email": "tt@test.com", "personalUse": true}, ...
  1 | [{"email": "example@example.com", "personalUse": true}, ...
```

Now you can use `jsonb_set` again to update original JSON.